# Saved PNG image is a bit larger than canvas size in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, kineticjs

newbie here.

I was testing out KinecticJS and I made several tech demos. The canvas size is set to 700x900 and I then loaded several SVG paths. On the browser winder they look really good: clean clear crisp, no pixelation on the edges.

In firefox when I right click and choose "View Image". The resulting image is of 875x1125, increased by 25%! This image when saved and viewed at 100% is fuzzy on the edges and not crisp at all!

Did I do something wrong? I tried to change the display scale in firefox but the result is still the same.

JSFiddle url is provided in the comments. It's a tech demo so all it does it draggable body parts.

Comment: can you post a minimal test case on jsfiddle.net or similar?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YshZc/

Comment: The web app works on all browsers but the save image is only a right-click option on Firefox so I am only asking about firefox. Thx

Comment: When I do "View Image", mine is 700x900.

Comment: After I changed Windows dpi setting to 100% (used to be 125%) the issue went away. Thanks Jeff.